# Plotting with sgplot and ODS on SAS

Tags: statistics, sas, ods

Here's my dataset

Column 1:
Lipid level

Column 2:
Age

Column 3:
Fat content category

Column 4:
Gender (1=male)

```
   0.73      1      1   1
   0.67      1      2   1
   0.15      1      3   1
   0.86      2      1   1
   0.67      2      2   1
   0.15      2      3   1
   0.94      3      1   1
   0.81      3      2   1
   0.26      3      3   1
   0.23      4      1   2
   1.40      4      1   1
   1.32      4      2   1
   0.15      4      3   1
   1.62      5      1   1
   1.41      5      2   1
   0.78      5      3   1
   9.78      5      1   1
```

Here's a few different analysis I'm running with this code but I'm not so sure why SAS is not compiling.

Before doing anything else, I set up a permanent library manually.

```
libname di ‘c:\diet’;
data di.HW3 Data;
infile hw3 data.sas;
input Lipidlevel Age Fatcontent Gender;
run;
```

Next, I want to produce a plot using ODS of Lipid Level by Fat Content Category for each Age Group.

```
ods graphics on;
proc sgplot data=newdiet;
var=Age;
scatter Age/Lipidlevel
ods graphics off;
```

To make it more clear how would I make one line for each Age Group connecting the 3 data point, color each line with a different color and represent each data point by a star, and make a legend below the X axis and create a label for the graph? (I thought this last part came automatically)

Now I want to produce two different sets of summary statistics using ODS.  a) Shows the mean, median, sample size and standard deviation of the Lipid Level for each Age Group.

```
Proc means data=newdiet;
var Lipidlevel;
run;
```

b) reports the sample size, mean and standard deviation of the Lipid Level for each Fat Content Category.

```
Proc means data=newdiet;
var Lipidlevel;
run;
```

Lastly, can anyone give me some advice on stratifying the data as follows?  I want to create labels and formats for both the Age Group and Fat Content Category variables. The age groups are coded 1 to 5 and correspond to: 15-24; 25-34; 35-44; 45-54; 55-64. The fat content categories are coded 1 to 3 and correspond to: extremely low; fairly low; moderately low.  I have no idea how to do this. The only way I can think of is to go into the original dataset and sort them out manually.

Comment: I am unsure what you are looking for, exactly, for the plot.  What is on the X and Y axis?  What is the grouping variable?  How do you want the scatter connected if there are multiple values for an X value?

Comment: Okay we would want fat content on X and on Y axis we would want lipid level.  The grouping variable would be by age.  Can the scatter points be connected by respective age group?

Comment: For age group 4, you have 2 observations with FatContent=1.  If you start connecting points with a line, you will have a vertical line between those.  Is that what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few questions in here.

Question in comments on the plot.

PROC Means -- use the class statement.  You can get what you want in 1 statement;

```
proc means data=newdiet mean std median;
class age Fatcontent;
ways 1 ;
var Lipidlevel;
run;
```

`CLASS` tells the Procedure how to group the data.  The `WAYS 1` says to calculate separately.  Otherwise it assumes this is a drill through path.

This produces:

```
                        Analysis Variable : Lipidlevel

                        N
        Fatcontent    Obs            Mean         Std Dev          Median

                 1      7       2.2228571       3.3628892       0.9400000

                 2      5       0.9760000       0.3610817       0.8100000

                 3      5       0.2980000       0.2736238       0.1500000


                        Analysis Variable : Lipidlevel

                        N
               Age    Obs            Mean         Std Dev          Median

                 1      3       0.5166667       0.3189566       0.6700000

                 2      3       0.5600000       0.3675595       0.6700000

                 3      3       0.6700000       0.3609709       0.8100000

                 4      4       0.7750000       0.6770771       0.7750000

                 5      4       3.3975000       4.2699444       1.5150000
```

Comment: I don't know about you, but is the above listed code working properly?